# Should I return 204 - No Content in a Json REST store implementation?

Tags: json, http, rest

I implemented a library to create JSON REST stores, and am finalising the API.
In the API, the developer can chose whether it will echo, or NOT echo,  the data back after a PUT and a POST.

Right now,

```
ECHO IS ON:
 POST /users/ => status: 201 Created, data: as stored on server
 PUT /users/1 (NEW res) => status: 201 Created, data: as stored
 PUT /users/1 (EXISTING res) => status: 200 OK, data: as stored

ECHO IS OFF:
 POST /users/ => status: 201 Created, data: EMPTY <- Status not 204?
 PUT /users/1 (NEW res) => status: 201 Created, data: EMPTY <- Status not 204?
 PUT /users/1 (EXISTING res) => status: 200 Created, data: EMPTY <- Status not 204?
```

So, whereas if echo is ON everything looks clear (POST responds with 201, PUT responds with either 201 (new resources) or 200 (OK), things are a bit more uncertain when ECHO is off.

In case I do NOT want to return the record in the response, what should I return, the "legit" 201 (Created)/200 (OK), or -- since there is no data -- 204 (No Data)?

I know it's only a detail, but I have had this doubt since day 1 and I haven't yet managed to solve this one.

Comment: If stuff was stored it should be a 200, you should always return a message `{code:200, status:'success', message:'any message here will do'}` IMO:

Answer (score 0):

In your echo off mode:

```
POST /users/ => status: 201 Created, data: EMPTY
```

Creating a resource, 201 Created would be the best response, and you may perfectly return nothing as well. It's also a good practice to return the URI of the new resource as the Location header.

```
PUT /users/1 (NEW res) => status: 201 Created, data: EMPTY
```

Exactly the same as in the previous POST request.

```
PUT /users/1 (EXISTING res) => status: 204 No Content
```

If you are updating a resource and you aren't going to return anything, a 204 No Content is the best so the browser/client knows it doesn't have to wait for a response body.

EDIT: I've removed the recommendation I made for the response body of the POST 201 Created case, since the [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) doesn't technically say to return the new resource, and it is also not mentioned in the [new spec](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html#status.201) edited by [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke).

Comment: No, the HTTP spec does NOT recommend returning the entity. It mentions that a *description* *can* be returned, that's all (note the relevant spec is now http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html#status.201).

Comment: @JulianReschke, until the draft you point out is approved which will make RFC 2616 obsolete, the current 2616 says "The response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s)". So in my opinion it does recommend it, but it won't anymore in the near future.

Comment: the cited document *has* been approved, see datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics/…; also even RFC 2616 doesn't recommend to "return the new resource"; it talks about a *description*

Comment: Fair point. I've edited the response taking into account your comments. RFC 2616 description "an entity containing a list of resource characteristics and location(s)" on that isn't clear enough to me though.

Answer (score 0):

If your server created a resource, 201 is the right status code, even if you do not send the new content.

If your server updated a resource, both 200 and 204 work.

You may want to have a look at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-http-prefer-18#section-4.2